# tkinter Error in code editors : 'tkinter' module has no attribute

Tags: python, ubuntu, tkinter, module, atom-editor

**That's the Error I'm getting **

```
    AttributeError: partially initialized module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'Tk' (most likely
 due to a circular import). Did you mean: 'tk'?
```

**When I run this code : **

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

myLabel = Label(root, text="Hellow World!")

myLabel.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I'm trying to solve this problem for days and I found out that the code has no any Errors
because this only happen in code Editors like **VScode** and **Atom** but it did work on
[replit.com](https://replit.com) .

**The question is :**
why is that happen?
do I have to install something?
or because I'm using linux(Ubuntu)?

Comment: Most likely you have named your script as `tkinter.py`.

Comment: Generally you only want to import a module once... Since you're using `import tkinter as tk`, your `from tkinter import *` is redundant since you can access all the attributes from the `tk` name. If there are conflicting names (eg `tk` is the name of an object in `tkinter`), then that could be the cause of the issue.